# Как сделать индекс с определенного числа

Tags: python, pandas

Есть df, в котором есть индекс с номером по порядку. Как мне сделать индекс с определенного числа? К примеру с 49362 и по порядку. Знаю, что банальный вопрос, но ничего найти не могу. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы знаете что текущий индекс начинается с нуля и считает числа подряд, то можно подвинуть текущий индекс на 49362 ([pandas.DataFrame.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) устанавливает индекс):

> ```
> df = df.set_index(keys=df.index + 49362)
> ```

Если вы не хотите зависеть от текущего индекса, создайте новый индекс ([pandas.RangeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html)):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10), 'b': range(0, 100, 10)})
print(df)

start = 49362
index = pd.RangeIndex(start=start, stop=start + len(df))
df = df.set_index(keys=index)
print(df)
```

> ```
> $ python set-index.py
>    a   b
> 0  0   0
> 1  1  10
> 2  2  20
> 3  3  30
> 4  4  40
> 5  5  50
> 6  6  60
> 7  7  70
> 8  8  80
> 9  9  90
>        a   b
> 49362  0   0
> 49363  1  10
> 49364  2  20
> 49365  3  30
> 49366  4  40
> 49367  5  50
> 49368  6  60
> 49369  7  70
> 49370  8  80
> 49371  9  90
> ```